# Elegant and efficient algorithm for increasing values of a "vector<pair>"

Tags: c++

I need to find an element in a `vector<pair<int, float>>` and increase the second value.
I tried an approach.

```
template <typename K, typename V>
struct match_first {
    const K _k; match_first(const K& k) : _k(k) {}
    bool operator()(const pair<K, V>& el) const {
        return _k == el.first;
    }
};
```

Eg to use.:

```
vector< pair<int, float> > vec;
vec.push_back(make_pair(2, 3.0));
vec.push_back(make_pair(3, 5.0));
vec.push_back(make_pair(1, 1.0));

vector< pair<int, float> >::iterator it = find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), match_first<int, float>(3));
if (it != vec.end()) {
    it->second += 9;
}
```

There is a more efficient way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: Not unless it's sorted or you discover a different container works better for your overall needs.

Comment: Efficient in terms of what?

Comment: Computational complexity Big-O

Comment: Do you need to increase the second value of only one or of many elements? Do you have a (sorted) vector to begin with? How many elements are going to be in that container? Etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A map seems more natural:

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, float> m;
    m.insert(std::make_pair(2, 3.0));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(3, 5.0));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(1, 1.0));

    auto it = m.find(3);
    if (it != m.end()) {
        it->second += 9;
    }
}
```

It will also be faster because lookup is `O(log(n))`

You can reach the same complexity with a vector of *sorted* pairs by using `std::lower_bound` (or `std::equal_range` if keys can be repeated)

Comment: @DyP I said _lookup_ is O(log(n)). The rest is all obvious and common sense. My answer doesn't claim otherwise (also, I think your comments were a bit early with regards to my notes)

Comment: Actually, an unordered map might be even better, since you're already screwing around with the OP's ordering by using this map. The catch is that the OP's code looks very non-C++11ish.

Comment: Ok, I'll delete my comment. Failed to point out that if you include construction, the vector example is in O(N), whereas the map is in O(NlogN).

Comment: While a map seems a better data structure, it would not (directly) enable the case when the same key can have different values. In other words: if both (1, 3) and (1, 5) are valid pairs, a map would only store the latest one added. In addition, if the order of INSERTION of the points is important, the map would mess it up. For a stream of points which are, say, the output of a mathematical function I would use a vector of pairs instead of a map.

Comment: @Arrieta I think I addressed that. Also, if the order of insertion is "important", it still depends on _when_ it is important. You can have a multi-indexed collection, or a map _and_ a vector. He was asking about the performance, and I focused on the subject matter: **"efficient algorithm for increasing values of a “vector<pair>”"**

Comment: I like your answer, but I don't think it addresses my comment (that is, a novice would not know that the repeated entries would be overwritten, nor would s/he know that the order of insertion is lost).

Comment: @Arrieta I hope novices know how to find the documentation (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) because, that's not what SO is for (it is also not what his question asked)

Comment: I agree with you --- on 90% of the cases when I have a question (even more complex than this one), a quick search on cppreference (or similar) solves the problem in fifteen minutes. But I think that is why some people remain novices: they refuse to read readily available information. Oh, well.

Comment: @Arrieta It's not my vocation to solve _that_ particular problem (nor could we, if we tried). That's also a good reason why I don't assume the OPs are lazy/dumb: likely they wouldn't be here, and even if the exception is the case, it doesn't matter because there is no better way to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your constrains. If you have the unique key (the first element) you can use `std::map<K,V>` to hold your objects. Then increasing it is easy. If `V` has a default constructor initializing it to zero, you can even skip adding new elements and just increment (I am not sure it will work with ints through).

```
std::map<K,V> data;
data[key] = data[key] + 1;
```

the `[]` operator used for non-existent key will create the object for you using its default constructor. To just access data use `at` or `find` methods.

Answer (score 0):

extending sehe's answer: You can use `std::multimap` in the same way if you may have duplicate keys. This container also keeps the `<K,V>` pair in sorted order(keys) so binary search approach obviously speed up things.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact answer to your question: it depends.

My first answer is: use `std::find_if` (available in `<algorithm>`, part of the C++ Standard Library), then profile your code. If the search turns out to be a bottleneck worthy of concern, then try another approach.

Beware of using a `std::map`, as it will sort the pairs by their first component (that is, the insertion order will be lost). In addition, it will not allow you to store two pairs with the same first component.

As others have mentioned, you can work around this caveats (if they are indeed caveats to your problem), but, like I mentioned before, it would only be worth your while if you demonstrate first that the search turned out to be a bottleneck after using the standard algorithms.